# R ggplot too many categorical labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I have this plot that has too many groups pretty much and would like to space them out. It looks pretty bad as the labels are all bunched up. Is there a way to put like spacing or padding between my graph?

```
sea_abnb %>%
  group_by(neighbourhood) %>%
  summarize(neigh_med = median(price)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(neighbourhood, neigh_med), y=neigh_med)) +
    labs(x="Room type", y="Median Price per Night") +
    geom_point() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image: My Plot Here]

Comment: You could make the font size smaller so the labels do not overlap. However, I don't think the result will be pretty. I would ask myself whether I really need all the labels.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow by the way!

Comment: Perhaps a map of Seattle with colors overlaid on its districts to represent the prices would be a better way to show the data?

Comment: Or convert to an interactive plot (conversion from `ggplot` to `plotly` is quite easy) with the labels as tooltips when the user mouses over the points.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you save you can set the dimensions. You can stretch it out by increasing the height. It is probably better to have the labels on the longer axis of your plot. However, this type of plot might not be the best way to present your data.

```
ggsave(
  filename="my_plot.png",
  width = 400,
  height = 800,
  units = c("in", "cm", "mm"),
)
```

One possibility would be to split the data into two panels, and maybe add bars to improve the looks:

[image]

```
d <- data.frame(neighbourhood = paste0("ID",1:70), neigh_med = runif(70, 0, 100))

d <- d %>% mutate(t = ifelse(neigh_med <= median(neigh_med), "l", "h" ))

ggplot(d, aes(x=reorder(neighbourhood, neigh_med), y=neigh_med)) +
  labs(x="Room type", y="Median Price per Night") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.2) +
  geom_point()+
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~t, scales = "free_y" ) +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Finally, if some labels are much longer than others, you can abbreviate them with `substr`

Answer (score 1):

@Allan Cameron is right, a map would be a great way to plot this data.

I've been meaning to give `rgdal` a try, and this question gave me an excuse.

Let's plot median listing price by zipcode.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(broom)
library(data.table)
sea_abnb <- fread("http://data.insideairbnb.com/united-states/wa/seattle/2020-03-17/data/listings.csv.gz")

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/83fc2e72903343aabff6de8cb445b81c_2.zip",temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
seat.shp <- readOGR(temp2, stringsAsFactors = F)
seat.shp@data$id <- rownames(seat.shp@data)
seat.points <- tidy(seat.shp, region="id") %>% left_join(seat.shp@data, by="id")
seat.df <- sea_abnb %>%
  mutate(ZIPCODE = str_extract(zipcode,"^[0-9]{5}"),
         price = as.numeric(str_replace(price,"\\$",""))) %>%
  group_by(ZIPCODE) %>%
  summarize(zip_med = median(price,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(ZIPCODE, zip_med) %>% 
  right_join(seat.points)

ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = seat.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = ZIPCODE, fill = zip_med), colour = "black") +
  coord_map(xlim= c(-122.5,-122.05), ylim = c(47.45,47.8)) + labs(y= "Lattitude", x = "Longitude") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Median Zipcode\nListing Price"))
```

[image]